# Any ways to detect changes in LiteDb?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nosql, litedb

Is there any ways to detect differences between model and LiteDb?

For example.

```
[Table('table')]
public class Table
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And liteDb has table with the same columns.

I wanna add a new property into my model

```
[Table('table')]
public class Table
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string NewCol { get; set; }
}
```

How can I detect that **NewCol** is recently added into model and there no equal column into LiteDb table

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to detect this change on model because for LiteDB engine, both classes are converted into `BsonDocument`, a generic object representation to be converted into JSON/BSON to store on disk. In your example, if you insert document with your first model, LiteDB convert to:

`{ Id: 1, Name: "John" }`

In second model, you will have:

`{ Id: 1, Name: "John", NewCol: "anyvalue" }`

In both cases you can load/save data because missing properties are defined as NULL.

But, if you need track database model version, you can use internal "UserVersion" for this. It's a simple internal `int` get/set value that you can track database model version. You can check this issue for more information: https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/778